# Adjusting UILabel size and text position after calling sizeToFit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Current result:

[image: Current result]

I'm able to adjust the size of the label by calling `sizeToFit`, which does a decent job at framing the text -- however, even with `NSTextAlignmentCenter`, the text is not exactly centered horizontally or vertically. To adjust the text positioning within the label, I've overridden `drawTextInRect:` to adjust the text rect using `UIEdgeInserts`.

Intended result:

[image]

Now that the text is centered, I'd like to expand the label to add some space between the text and the label edges. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by creating a subclass of `UILabel`, and overriding `intrinsicContentSize` instead of `drawTextInRect:`.

```
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        self.sizeToFit()
        frame = frame.rectByInsetting(dx: -12, dy: -6)
        var size = frame.size
        return size
    }
```

Of course, the text alignment also needs to be set to centered.